# How to change the colour of certain boxplots while hue is already in use

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I am trying to plot my data which is already split by hue, but I want the first and forth boxplots coloured in red to show that they are differentially expressed. Having the hue already assigned to type, I can't seem to change the colour of the boxplots, I haven't been able to find a solution to this, and it would be a great help if I can get some advice on how to change them.
Here is some example code below (my actual data has more than 100 points for each distance and more than 10 distances):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'TPM': [358934.30, 21984.51, 621008.07, 0.000254, 123456.78, 98765.43, 456.78, 0.000004,
            28413.26, 111.11, 98765.43, 8888.88, 3456.78, 789.01, 987654.32, 0.123456,
            7890.12, 12345.67, 0.000001, 987654.32, 0.000001, 12345.67, 987.65, 0.000001],
    'Type': ['tumour', 'normal', 'tumour', 'normal', 'tumour', 'normal', 'tumour', 'normal',
             'tumour', 'normal', 'tumour', 'normal', 'tumour', 'normal', 'tumour', 'normal',
             'tumour', 'normal', 'tumour', 'normal', 'tumour', 'normal', 'tumour', 'normal'],
    'Distance': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2,
                 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


#THE PLOT:
plt.figure(figsize=(30, 15))


# Boxplot using the custom palette
sns.boxplot(data=genes_df, x='distance', y='TPM', hue='type', width=0.9)

plt.yscale('log')

# place the legend outside
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.95, 0.98), loc='upper left')

plt.xticks(rotation=90)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

and this is what I get as a result:
[image]

I have tried adding another column which would differentiate the differentially expressed genes from the rest, but I have not found a way to plot this.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including a minimal dataset (in short, code which when copy/pasted gives a minimal graph)

Comment: @mozway I have tried adding an example, hope this helps

Comment: Make your figure as `ax = sns.boxplot(data=data, x='Distance', y='TPM', hue='Type', width=0.9)`,  the get the `patch` of the box you want to change.  `box_1 = ax.patches[1]` and `box_4 = ax.patches[5]`, then set color `box_1.set_facecolor('red')` ,   `box_4.set_facecolor('red')`